# Using astype on a koalas column gives strange result of datatype of column as <U0

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-koalas

I have a column in my koalas dataframe called `purchase_date`. In databricks notebook, with runtime as 10.3, when I do the following lines of code, I get the dtype of the `purchase_date` column as `<U0`. I am not able to understand why this is happenning.

My code which caused this is as follows (in Databricks runtime 10.3):

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

print("Datatype of purchase_date before astype:" , my_ks_dataframe['purchase_date'].dtype)  # Datatype of purchase_date before astype: object

# Using the astype
my_ks_dataframe['purchase_date'] = my_ks_dataframe['purchase_date'].astype('str') 

print("Datatype of purchase_date before astype:" , my_ks_dataframe['purchase_date'].dtype) # Datatype of purchase_date after astype: <U0
```

I am not sure why I see this behaviour in Databricks runtime 10.3. When I execute the same code in Databricks runtime 8.1, I get the desired datatype for purchase_date as `object` before and after astype usage.

```
# print result in Databricks runtime 8.1

Datatype of purchase_date before astype: object
Datatype of purchase_date after astype: object
```

Comment: Have you resovled this?